# Why is sending a Python response not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to log into Facebook using Python by sending a post request to Facebook. What I'm stuck with is that it's not sending the request because I made the script save the response into an HTML file and display it. All I get is the login page saved into my `response.html` where the expected page is an error from Facebook that the password is wrong.

```
import requests
a = open('response.html', 'a', encoding='ISO-8859-1')
data = {
'lsd':'???',
'email':'???',
'pass':'???',
'timezone':'???',
'lgndim':'???',
'lgnrnd':'???',
'lgnjs':???,
'ab_test_data':'???',
'locale':'???',
'next':'https://www.facebook.com/',
'login_source':'???',
}
r = requests.post('https://facebook.com', data)
a.write(r.text)
a.close()
```

Comment: You didn't close your file, so some or all of the contents written to it may never get flushed to disk.  ``a.close`` merely refers to the close method of the file: ``a.close()`` would actually call it.

Comment: Are you sure that's the form post URL? Open dev tools on browser and see where the login form goes to. Also you might need a library requests to keep track of your cookies.

Comment: I did `a.close()` but for some weird reason stackoverflow deleted it